# How can I share files from a parent git repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly inexperienced with git, I've tried to research how to achieve what I want but haven't been successful.

I have a project which makes up the base of an IRC bot, to which I can add files and make new bots that do different things. So the main repository looks something like this (simplified):

```
bot.py
config.json
modules
- core.py
```

Now, if I create a new bot based on that, I just need to add files to the module folder and alter the config. I want to have two separate repositories for the two bots. However, if I alter these base files in the main project, I want the same files to be updated in the new bot's repository as well. I don't know what the best way to manage this is though, I hope I made sense. I'd like to manage it through Github Desktop if possible, but any solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage that by using branches, let's say you have the master branch, create 3 other branches:

- base
- bot1
- bot2

You can do it:

```
git branch base 
git branch bot1
git branch bot2
```

Checkout your `base` branch:  `git checkout base`, Make your changes, whenever you feel the changes are ready to be moved to the other branches. use the `merge` for that:

```
git checkout bot1
git merge base
```